# Python- in print statement syntax error but it is correct

Tags: python-3.x

```
while True:
    reply = input('Enter text:')
    if reply == 'stop':
        break
    elif not reply.isdigit():
        print('Bad!' * 8)
    else:
        num = int(reply)
        if num < 20:
            print('low')
        else:
            print(num ** 2)
print('Bye')
```

**error showing**
File "", line 13
print('bye')
......^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, you type ‘stop’ and you get the error?